# FB.API 'Undefined' : news.reads activity

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to implement the Facebook news.reads App - I'm just missing one final step - executing the POST to FB. When I look at the Firebug console, it appears that the POST is in fact working...or at least there are no errors. Check out the output below:

Post:

---

```
__a 1
__user  myID
app APPID
fb_dtsg AQBi1J4k
href    http://www.around-around.com/today-show/
phstamp 1658166105497452107119
ref 
Source
fb_dtsg=AQBi1J4k&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.around-around.com%2Ftoday-show%2F&app=183125741799131&ref=&__user=63802158&__a=1&phstamp=1658166105497452107119
```

(I've validated that the meta data from the URL is correct).

---

But the response I get from FB is strange:

---

for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null}

---

No idea what to do with that. The referrer also seems to be the recommendation bar (which I'm using):

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/recommendations_bar.php?action=like&api_key=APPID&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D11%23cb%3Df274495fd8bd4fc%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.around-around.com%252Ff2b573e1404fec4%26domain%3Dwww.around-around.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.around-around.com%2Ftoday-show%2F&locale=en_US&num_recommendations=2&read_time=30&sdk=joey&side=right&site=around-around.com&trigger=onvisible

So, I'm also using this code to try to automatically force a POST news.reads action.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readArticle()
  {
      FB.api(
        '/me/news.reads',
        'post',
        { article: '<?php the_permalink(); ?>' },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Error occured');
           } else {
              alert('Article read was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
  </script>
```

(you won't see this code on the site, as it's only firing for admins as of now)

I'm not getting any alerts so something is causing this to misfire...but using the recommendation bar would be preferable to us.

Anyways, any help would be appreciated.

Luke

Comment: MISTITLED THIS. Sorry folks. The FP.APi is not 'undefined' - it's just throwing that weird response.

Comment: What response are you getting to the FB.api() call? that `for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null}` should only be present on Facebook's own AJAX endpoints, not the API

Comment: Response Headersview source
Cache-Control private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection keep-alive
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Type application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
Date Mon, 24 Sep 2012 19:54:45 GMT
Expires Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma no-cache
Transfer-Encoding chunked
X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
X-FB-Debug TmIL8xgdAtYSlZS0Pt3/NExqctm1lFPHor4TuCm6Nb8=
X-Frame-Options DENY
X-XSS-Protection 1; mode=block

Comment: Sorry, that's pretty ugly, but hopefully that gives you an idea. I'm thinking that that part of the recommendation bar is still in beta? maybe?

Comment: It's really unclear what your issue is - that looks like regular response headers - what is the result of your call to FB.api() - it should be a string with the ID of the posted action, or an object containing the exception that occurred

Comment: Is this what you mean? Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
__a 1
__user 63802158
app 183125741799131
fb_dtsg AQBJdMjU
href http://www.around-around.com/dear-snow-day/
phstamp 1658166741007710685122
ref 
Source
fb_dtsg=AQBJdMjU&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.around-around.com%2Fdear-snow-day%2F&app=183125741799131&ref=&__user=63802158&__a=1&phstamp=1658166741007710685122